# How to switch between NSObject Class to ViewController

Tags: iphone, ios, nsobject

I'm having to class one which extends `NSObject` and second the view controller.

What is my problem is that I want to go to `NSObject` to `view controller` that loads my `xib` file of that `view controller`.

I have used the traditional, with no success thus far.
Suppose NSObject is MagentoLogin.m and I want to go to viewController, how can I achieve this?

Comment: It would be easier to help if you added some code to the question showing what you have already tried. This would probably also clarify a question a little bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
MyAppDelegate *appDelegate = (MyAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
[appDelegate.navigationController presentViewController:myNewViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

try this hope it will help

Comment: MyAppDelegate is our appdelegate?? and yes i am  not calling the view from app delegate so does it help me ??

Comment: In this Example m pushing my view with `NavigationController` and now what's going wrong with you ?

Comment: I have updated my question and yes i want to go from non delegate class which extends the NSObject